# PHP function call causes infinite recursion

Tags: php, recursion, tree

Function `nested()` return array of nested elements which in turn are instances of the same class as parent.

Function `drop()` contains anonymous function `push()` which recursively walk through the tree but for some reason it causes infinite loop and I can't figure out why. I use condition `count($set) > 0` to prevent infinite recursion so it might stop recursively call `push()` function when it comes to the end of the tree but it doesn't stop.

```
public function nested() {
    $list = [];
    $categories = Db::o()->select("categories(c)", [
            "[><]_categories(_c)" => ["c.id" => "child"]
        ], [
            "c.id",
            "c.title",
            "c.alias"
        ], [
            "_c.parent" => $this->id
    ]);

    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $list[] = new Category($category['id'], $category['title'], $category['alias']);
    }
    return $list;
}

public function drop() {
    $push = function ($set) use (&$push) {
        if (count($set) > 0) {
            foreach($set as $child) {
                $this->subset .= $child->id;
                $push($child->nested());
            }
        }
    };

    $push($this->nested());
    $this->dropSubset();
}
```

Comment: `->nested()` returns maybe allways the same result, see the SQL you do. Are the `$this->id` always different?

Comment: JustOnUnderMillions thank you. managed to solve this, code actually work. the problem was in database closure table. Parent1 -> Child1 -> Parent1 so it leads to infinite tree